# Какой компилятор является родоначальником всех компиляторов?

Tags: компиляция, компилятор, история

Чтобы создать программу нужно написать код на каком-то языке программирования и откомпилировать его в машинный код.

Чтобы откомпилировать, нужен компилятор, который так же является программой.

Кто то написал код компилятора и откомпелировал его, вероятно, на другом компиляторе.

Вероятно (или как может быть иначе?) существует первоначальный компилятор, написанный, на машинных кодах. Известен ли он, где можно его скачать в виде файла? Кто-нибудь проводил расследование и прослеживал цепочку, начиная с какого-нибудь известного компилятора, например **g++** (хотя бы может кто знает, на чем был написан и в чем откомпилирован **g++**, а там можно будет создавать отдельный вопрос по каждому)?

Comment: Одного первоначального компилятора нет. Вероятно, до появления Си большинство компиляторов писалось или на Ассемблере или в машинных кодах.

Comment: ну да, для ассемблера тоже нужет компилятор. Речь **не** идет о том, чтобы найти **единственный** первоначальный компилятор, но хотя бы какой-нибудь, из которого произошел, например, `g++`

Comment: Прикол в том, что компилятор тогда считается хорошим, когда может скомпилировать сам себя ;)
Ну а самые первые компиляторы на ассемблере писались (нет, его не надо компилировать)

Comment: Чтобы писать на ассемблере не обязателен компилятор. Главное знать команды, и чтобы была табличка соответствий мнемоник команд и машинных кодов. Первоначальный компилятор языка Си возможно так и писался, в тетрадочке) C++ первоначально был надстройкой над Си, для него не нужно было отдельного компилятора.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80,_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81

Comment: А вот исходники первого компилятора С - https://github.com/mortdeus/legacy-cc

Comment: @insolor вероятно ) звучит забавно. Видно, вы эту эпоху не застали )

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Кобол и эпоху создания Си не застал. Но в тетрадочке в машинных кодах писал)

Comment: @insolor не нужен компилятор - очень интересно. По-вашему, процессор понимает последовательность символов mov ax, bx ?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, в качестве компилятора выступает человек, вот что я имел в виду.

Comment: @KAGGDesign таки там транслятор, а не компилятор. Предлагаю не продолжать игру в слова

Comment: @rjhdby да я лично с вами и не играл ни во что

Comment: @rjhdby Неужели таки Грейс Хоппер разработала ПЕРВЫЙ (сик!) в истории компилятор для ЯП? Это общепризнанный факт? (Что интересно, ведь и первым человеком-программистом тоже была женщина - Ада!)

Comment: @asianirish "Так об этом пишут газеты, А газеты всегда правы." В английской википедии также об этом сказано. У меня нет оснований не доверять вики в этом вопросе :)

Comment: @rjhdby Так на чем же был откомпелирован сам legacy-cc, ведь он сам написан на си?

Comment: @asianirish ну ядрён батон! У вас же целый гугл под рукой. https://geektimes.ru/post/114588/

Comment: @asianirish тут ведь вот в чем штука. Не важно на чем был написан первый компилятор, скорее всего на каком-то предыдущем языке, возможно даже не на одном. Важно, что он только тогда становится самодостаточным, когда может собрать сам себя.

Comment: [Bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)).